# Which to use when referencing in jQuery plugins - $(obj) vs obj

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm self learning and currently tackling jQuery plugins.

I've discovered a boiler plate that for iterating through elements on a page assigns $(this) to a global variable 'obj'.

```
var obj = $(this);
```

As a result in my functions I can use either `$(obj).someFunc()` or `obj.someFunc()` both work but if honest I don't really understand what the difference is.

So there's the question, what are the performance differences/benefits of both methods and which should I be using?

Comment: If you defined obj as you did above, there's no reason to use `$(obj)` because it is redundant. `$($($($($(obj)))))`

Comment: And inside a jQuery plugin, `this` is the jQuery object, so you're rewrapping it twice?

Comment: Depending on whether or not you're already inside the `this.each`

Comment: Yes the boiler plate I am using is wrapped in return this.each(function()....

Comment: I'd rather use var $obj = $(...) to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `obj` is already a jQuery object, which is the case when you do `var obj = $(this);`, then there is no need to pass it to jQuery *again*.

`$(obj)` is the same as `$($(this))`, which is clearly redundant.

Having a look at [`jQuery`'s documentation *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) also helps to understand what you can pass to `jQuery` (alias `$`):

- `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`
- `jQuery( element )`
- `jQuery( elementArray )`
- `jQuery( object )`
- `jQuery( jQuery object )`
- `jQuery()`

You see that passing a jQuery object is perfectly valid, but it will *clone* the passed object, which is probably not what you intend to do.

---

However, it might be worth pointing out that ***inside* a jQuery plugin method**, `this` is already a jQuery object, so you don't have to pass it to jQuery either.

More info here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring.

Comment: So I could ignore assigning $(this) to obj and just reference 'this'?

Comment: @Kryptonite: Depending on the context, yes. But you did not provide more information, so my suggestion would be: try it :)

Comment: @Kryptonite: Regarding your other comment: *Inside* the callback for `this.each`, `this` will of course refer to the DOM element only, because that's how `.each` works. In that case you have to pass `this` to `$`, just as always.

Answer (score 1):

If `obj.someFunc()` and `$(obj).someFunc()` both works and `someFunc` is a jQuery function then it means the `obj` is a jQuery object.

In that case `$(obj)` is just a redundant call.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is really simple - in the first case **$(obj).someFunc()**  you are calling $() every time. In the second case **obj.someFunc()**, you are calling it just once, and storing it's result in a variable called **obj**

Answer (score 0):

`var obj = $(this);`

It is like you created an instance of Class , you can access and use `obj` and it is better while using:

```
`$(obj)`
```

is redundant initialization it is like you created another instance of class and assign the same object to it. so there is no use of or I say any advantage of using it.